# Randomly change/mutate one value in a list

Tags: python, list, random, genetic-algorithm

I'm writing a genetic algorithm and want to randomly mutate a number within a list.

If I had a list, for example:

```
[1,2,3,4,5]
```

How could I take the list and change just one of the numbers to a random number, for example:

```
[1,2,7,4,5]
```

or

```
[1,3,3,4,5]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Just pick an index at random and pick a value at random in your loop

Comment: list[random.randint(0,len(list)] = random.randint(0,maxtobedefine) https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.randint.html

Comment: @Alexis those are the docs for numpy. There's no need to use numpy here to generate the random numbers unless the OP actually has an array

Comment: @Alexis: `IndexError`

Comment: also, it wouldn't be a good idea to name your variable `list`

Comment: agreed on the variable name, my_list would be better. i don't get the index error tho. the high value is exclusive. @fferri (found it, you're using random package,and 'i'm using numpy.random.randint())

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `random.randint`:

```
l=[1,2,3,4,5]
import random
l[random.randint(0,len(l)-1)]=random.randint(min(l),max(l)-1)
```

And now:

```
print(l)
```

Is (every time it's different, this is just a first-time-output):

```
[1, 4, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: This will give a `IndexError`, as `random.randint(a,b)` generates a number between `a` and `b` *inclusive*.

Comment: Definitely yes! :-)

Comment: Would you mind explaining what each bit is doing? 
    l[random.randint(0,len(l)-1)]=random.randint(min(l),max(l)-1)

Comment: @Perry Sorry for late reply, okay, so the first part `l[random.randint(0,len(l)-1)` is getting a random index of the list then assign that index of that lists to.., now it's the second part to assign the first part value, `random.randint(min(l),max(l)-1)` which is getting a random value between the minimum value and the maximum value.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`random.randrange`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange) and [`random.randint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange):

```
>>> import random
>>> index = random.randrange(len(mylist))
>>> mylist[index] = random.randint(minVal, maxVal)
```

Edit: if you want to *always* make a change (i.e. never leave the list unchanged), consider *incrementing* the item by a non-zero value:

```
>>> mylist[index] += random.choice([1, -1]) * random.randint(1, maxChange)
```

Comment: If the `minVal` and `maxVal` range is say for eg: 1, 10, then there is also a chance that this returns the same list `mylist`.

Comment: @Austin For a GA I would actually probably eat that possibility for the sake of maintaining randomness in the pool (not everything _has_ to change) but it's a fair point :) Anecdotal but I've generally found it faster to accept a null-swap in a tight loop than try avoid it

Comment: @roganjosh, It would be more a possible chance if the range is small; I don't think you can just ignore that when I believe some alternates could solve it.

Comment: @Austin: good point, I added a second example for always making a change

Comment: @Austin devil's advocate; if the range is small, convergence will be fast any way. You're better to squish extra "generations" in. If you can get 3 iterations in by accepting duplicates instead of one where you force a change... <shrug>. Anyway, the edit now covers both :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [random.randint](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.randrange):

```
import random
temp_list = [1,2,3,4,5]
temp_list[index_of_list] = random.randint(minValue, maxValue)
```

or you can try like:

```
temp_list[random.randint(0, (len(temp_list))-1)] = random.randint(minValue, maxValue)
```

Comment: What's `index`? :)

Answer (score 0):

Different approach to similar problem, I hope it will helps with different point of view :)

As long as I have list of *e.g.* mixed string elements I use enumerate and some random choice function (in my case from Numpy). *e.g.* when I have list of different atoms, from which I want to randomly choose one atom of only one type, I can wrote:

```
import numpy as np

mixed_atm_list = ["Pb", "C", "H", "Pb", "C", "C", "Sn", "H"]
random_choice_atm = "C"

find_idx = [idx for idx, atm in enumerate(mixed_atm_list) if atm == random_choice_atm]

randomly_selected_carbon_atom = np.random.choice(find_idx)
randomly_selected_carbon_atom = mixed_atm_list[randomly_selected_carbon_atom]
```